# Unexpected indent in Puppet's erb template output

Tags: ruby, erb, puppet

I have a problem with `to_yaml` in Puppet's `erb` templates.

The content of my `erb` template looks as follows:

```
<%= {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}.to_yaml %>
```

The output produced by Puppet is:

```
--- 
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

But I expect (no indent):

```
--- 
key1: value1
key2: value2
```

Do I make something wrong? Are both representations equivalent? I don't think so.

Comment: Did you try `<%-` to suppress leading whitespace? ([reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html))

Comment: It's passing strange. I can reproduce, but in `irb`, it's working all right - `irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml' ; {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}.to_yaml`

Comment: Yes... That is really strange. The correct output is produced via `irb`. It is (as expected): `"---\nkey1: value1\nkey2: value2\n"`

Comment: This is a ugly fix that removes two white spaces at the beginning of each line: `<%= {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}.to_yaml.gsub(/^\s{2}/, '') %>`

Comment: Should I open a ticket in Puppet?

Comment: Not yet ;-) Still got some things to try.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, the issue here is... ZAML.

Puppet [monkey patches](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/3.7.0/lib/puppet/util/monkey_patches.rb#L35-L45) the `to_yaml` method and routes it to `ZAML.dump` (at one time it was supposedly "faster", but that was in an age before Ruby 1.9 and Psych when Mammoths walked the earth and the Gods were full of anger).

```
> require 'yaml'
> puts YAML.dump({"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"})
---
key1: value1
key2: value2

> require 'puppet/util/zaml'
> puts ZAML.dump({"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"})
--- 
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Answer (score 0):

I double checked with even the latest Puppet (3.7) and this still occurs (Gist of my debugging [here](https://gist.github.com/petems/504a7bc576c53e6c3e72)).

But it wont cause any issues, they're interpreted the same

But they are syntactically the same:

[Puppet version](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---%0A%20%20key1%3A%20value1%0A%20%20key2%3A%20value2&type=json) vs [Ruby version](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---%0Akey1%3A%20value1%0Akey2%3A%20value2&type=json)

So it's not really a bug technically, even if it looks different.